# FFI returns a huge integer value instead of 0

Tags: c++, haskell, haskell-ffi

I've wrapped the 'NumericalIntegration' C++ library in Haskell. [Here](https://github.com/stla/numerical-integration) is the latest version of the package (the version on Hackage is older).

Here is the main part of the C++ code :

```cpp
class Integrand {
 private:
  std::function<double(double)> f;

 public:
  Integrand(std::function<double(double)>& f_) : f(f_) {}
  double operator()(const double x) const { return f(x); }
};

double integration(double f(double),
                   double lower,
                   double upper,
                   double relError,
                   int subdiv,
                   double* errorEstimate,
                   int* errorCode) {
  // Define the integrand.
  std::function<double(double)> f_ = [&](double x) { return f(x); };
  Integrand integrand(f_);
  // Define the integrator.
  Eigen::Integrator<double> integrator(subdiv);
  // Define a quadrature rule.
  Eigen::Integrator<double>::QuadratureRule rule =
      Eigen::Integrator<double>::GaussKronrod201;
  // Define the desired absolute error.
  double absError = 0.0;
  // Integrate.
  double result = integrator.quadratureAdaptive(integrand, lower, upper,
                                                absError, relError, rule);
  *errorEstimate = integrator.estimatedError();
  *errorCode = integrator.errorCode();
  return result;
}
```

And here is the main part of the Haskell code:

```hs
foreign import ccall safe "wrapper" funPtr
    :: (Double -> Double) -> IO (FunPtr (Double -> Double))

foreign import ccall safe "integration" c_integration
    :: FunPtr (Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Int
    -> Ptr Double -> Ptr Int -> IO Double

-- | Numerical integration.
integration :: (Double -> Double)       -- ^ integrand
            -> Double                   -- ^ lower bound
            -> Double                   -- ^ upper bound
            -> Double                   -- ^ desired relative error
            -> Int                      -- ^ number of subdivisions
            -> IO IntegralResult        -- ^ value, error estimate, error code
integration f lower upper relError subdiv = do
  errorEstimatePtr <- mallocBytes (sizeOf (0 :: Double))
  errorCodePtr <- mallocBytes (sizeOf (0 :: Int))
  fPtr <- funPtr f
  result <-
    c_integration fPtr lower upper relError subdiv errorEstimatePtr errorCodePtr
  errorEstimate <- peek errorEstimatePtr
  errorCode <- peek errorCodePtr
  let out = IntegralResult {_value = result, _error = errorEstimate, _code = errorCode}
  free errorEstimatePtr
  free errorCodePtr
  freeHaskellFunPtr fPtr
  return out
```

This works but there's a problem regarding the error code of the integration. When the integration is ok, the error code should be 0. Sometimes it is 0, as expected. But sometimes it is a huge integer number, nonsensical, though the integration is fine.

Would you have an idea about this issue? Why this strange error code? Is there something bad in my code? I'm not fluent in C++ (nor in Haskell). But apart this strange error code, the library seems to work very well.

Comment: What do you mean by "sometimes"? "For some inputs", or "nondeterministically some of the time" for inputs that have worked previously? What happens when you use the C++ version directly with the same test cases?

Comment: I don't understand the rational to use pointers for returned values. Even an old compiler can return an aggregate `struct` containing all information. Not knowing about Haskell's type system, error in old C code are usually indicated by negative numbers, which translate to high positive values if the 2's complement is bit_casted to unsigned. Because native floating point has limited precision, in case of occurence of NaN or INF in intermediate calculations, the rest of the calculations are not considered reliable.

Comment: Nondeterministically, this is random. When I run an integration, and I rerun the same, the error code can change. I don't know how to use directly use the C++ library.

Comment: @Red.Wave Do you mean I should remove the "*" in the code `*errorCode = integrator.errorCode();`?

Comment: Admittedly it's been a while since I've done C, but don't function pointers usually need the pointer sigil? i.e. shouldn't the first argument to `integration` be `double (*f)(double)`? (Or has C++ changed this perhaps?)

Comment: @DanielWagner I don't know. But I use the C++ library **functional** and it works like this. This is C++11 by the way. The checks on Github actions work, except for Mac.

Comment: `struct integration_result{ int error; double value; double accuracy;};` that should be the return type. Now you can remove the pointers from the API. Next: the input to your API function needs to be a function pointer, so Daniel has a point in that regard. But the initializer for `integrand` can be `f` itself. You don't need the lambda here, because the signature is compatible. You certainly don't need to create an extra instance of `std::function`: `Integrand integrand{f};` will do. But you don't even need that class, just `integrator.quadratureAdaptive(f,/*..*/);` is much better.

Comment: @Red.Wave Structs are somewhat more annoying (not impossible or even hard, just more annoying) to handle with the Haskell FFI than output-by-pointer.

Comment: @DanielWagner that is poor design. The idiomatic usage of raw pointers in C++ is to bury them deep down a well-interfaced class.

Comment: @Red.Wave the FFI is primarily an interface to C, not to C++. The idea is to keep the interface between the languages raw&primitive and instead write appropriate high-level wrappers at each end, as appropriate for the respective languages. Haskell uses data structures quite different from what you find in OO languages, after all.

Comment: @leftaroundabout **`struct`** is one of the very first ***primitives*** of **C** with regards to **structured programming** (not *OOP* or anything). Not working it out is just irresponsible working.

Comment: @Red.Wave but structs don't translate to Haskell in a single, obvious way. Haskell does of course have records which can be used in a similar way, but only with caveats regarding strictness and scoping. As Daniel Wagner wrote, these can be overcome, but often it's just easier to not bother, leave the FFI part completely unstructured and build a pure interface that goes with the grain of the language you're actually programming in, instead of against the grain because you need to follow what structuring made sense for another language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the `x86_64` platform, a Haskell `Int` is 64 bits while a C `int` is 32 bits.  (A C `long` is 64 bits.)  In your code, you are picking up garbage in the upper bytes and getting an absurdly large 64-bit integer whose lowest 32-bits are zero, no doubt.

Anyway, there's a module `Foreign.C` that contains newtypes `CInt`, `CDouble`, etc. that are intended to match the corresponding C types on the target platform, and I think it's considered good practice to always use those:

```
import Foreign
import Foreign.C

foreign import ccall safe "wrapper" funPtr
    :: (CDouble -> CDouble) -> IO (FunPtr (CDouble -> CDouble))

foreign import ccall safe "integration" c_integration
    :: FunPtr (CDouble -> CDouble) -> CDouble -> CDouble -> CDouble -> CInt
    -> Ptr CDouble -> Ptr CInt -> IO CDouble
```

Of course, since these are newtypes, there is the bother of wrapping and unwrapping, though usually `fromIntegral` takes care of that automatically, while also converting across bit sizes:

```
errorCode <- fromIntegral <$> peek errorCodePtr
```

But, as a less portable alternative, you could stick with `Double` and `Int32` in your `foreign import` declarations, provided you are only targeting platforms where C `int`s are 32 bits.

Also note that, if you get the types right, then `malloc` is a type-safe alternative to `mallocBytes`:

```
errorCodePtr <- malloc
```

The type of the `Ptr` determines the correct number of bytes to allocate here.

Comment: Thanks! It works now. Would you whether it's possible to convert `CDouble` to `Double`? I would prefer `Double` in the result.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent people often use `realToFrac` for this, though [that's actually problematic](https://ro-che.info/articles/2019-05-14-convert-cdouble-to-double).

Comment: @leftaroundabout Ah yes, I was looking for `fromRealToFrac` ^^

Comment: Thanks @leftaroundabout. I was thinking about this issue. If I want to return Double, I can check if the CDouble is NaN, in which case I return a NaN Double. I can also check if the CDouble is Infinity, in which case I return a Double Infinity. No ? Does it make sense ?